# DB2 java connection driver

Tags: java, db2

I've just installed DB2 Express-C version 10.1 (the newest) and I've tried to make a connection to a SAMPLE database. I've already done t through db2.exe, all done normally.
here is my java code

```
    String url = "jdbc:db2:SAMPLE";
    String user = "db2admin";
    String password = "db2admin";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // Load the DB2 JDBC Type 2 Driver with DriverManager
        //Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");
        //Driver d = new COM.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver();
        Driver d = new COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver();
        if(!d.jdbcCompliant()) System.console().printf("jdbc driver is not ccompliant");
        //DriverManager.registerDriver(new COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver());
        DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
        if(!d.acceptsURL(url))
            throw new SQLException("url \"" + url + "\" is not accepted by jdbc driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        /* do some work */
        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output is

```
java.sql.SQLException: url "jdbc:db2:SAMPLE" is not accepted by jdbc driver
```

what is the problem?
I've added .zip with driver to my library so it is found properly.
Maybe I have some wrong settings?

Comment: Have you tried use Driver Type 4, since you are using latest version of DB2, it is worth trying switch to latest driver as well. And also when use Driver Type 4, the connection url should be formatted as jdbc:db2://{IP}:{port}/SAMPLE

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: url "jdbc:db2://127.0.0.1:50000/SAMPLE" is not accepted by jdbc driver

Comment: the problem is solved - I just think that app driver is deprecated.

Comment: I used com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver() adding db2jcc.jar + licent jar + used your url format